# How can I temporarily disable ActionCable subscriptions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to debug some odd behavior with my application and was trying to see if "disabling" action cable streams/subscriptions in development would correct the behavior - but how can I stop this without ripping out large amounts of code?

I'm currently using Rails 5.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `//= require cable` from `application.js`

Comment: Do you mean remove `//= require action_cable` from `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js` ?  I didn't set mine up with the line you mentioned, but perhaps that's part of my problem. Still researching...

Comment: I mean to remove `//= require cable` (`app/assets/javascripts/cable.js`) from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: This didn't seem to help me. I still see the [ActionCable] messages in development terminal.

Comment: Turns out I had to get rid of my cached assets.  I did this by deleting my tmp folder and rerunning my development rails server.